# blogdown `title` won't display on rendered `_index.html`

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown

I created an `_index.Rmd` file in my blogdown `/*/content/` directory and the body of the `_index.Rmd` file looks like this:

````
---
title: "Home"
date: "2016-05-05T21:48:51-07:00"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Welcome to the home page of this blogdown site.
````

I would expect to see a "Home" title heading but nothing appears. I presume this is an intentional design choice. I can understand why, but in my case I want the title that I specify in the YAML to showup on the rendered `_index.html` file. How do I achieve this goal?

[image]

Comment: According to [author's R series book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/configuration.html#toml-syntax) you would adjust title in the `config.toml` file.

Comment: The TOML in my `config.toml` does specify `title = "Home"`, but that only changes the title on _Chrome_ tab (or _Firefox_ tab). It does not insert the "Home" title on my `_index.html` file.

Comment: I believe it is advised not to touch the rendered `.html` files. Possibly some `GO` language process runs to render titles, footers, sidebars, etc. per theme. If you get your rendered output, why do you need to see it in `.html` file?

Comment: If I click on the "About" page there is an "About" title at the top of the page. When I click on the "Li" logo it takes me home, and I'd like to have a "Home" title at the top of the page. I can add a heading `# Home` but it's too small, and not as elegant as putting the actual title "Home".

Comment: Hmmm...so `About` shows up (not on tab but on top of web page) but not `Home` And both have same R markdown? I will circle back testing on my blogdown setup. Possibly a special mapping takes place with index pages.

Comment: All my R Markdown pages have `title = "XYZ"` in their YAML, but the `_index.Rmd` is the one exception that doesn't actually display the title. Note that this is also the one file I had to create myself (as shown in the original question). Thanks

Comment: In this case, embed raw html code for the title, then you can specify the font-size & stuff. for example, `<h2 id="title" style="
    font-size: 2em;
">Put Your super fancy home title here</h2>`

Comment: @TC Zhang Thanks that works. But the font style is off. How do I specify the correct font type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the index (main) page has special treatment with this theme. How you can change this is go to `themes/(yourtheme)/layouts/index.html`. It would look something like:

```
{{ partial "header.html" . }}

<main class="content">

  <div class="list">
     {{ range (.Paginate ((where .Data.Pages "Type" "post").GroupByDate "2006")).PageGroups }}    
  <h2 class="list-title">{{ .Key }}</h2>
    {{ range .Pages }}

    {{ partial "list-item.html" . }}

    {{ end }}
    {{ end }}
  </div>  

  {{ partial "pagination.html" . }}

</main>

{{ partial "footer.html" . }}
```

Now you can edit this file to add the desired title in many ways, for example if you want the same style as a post title would have you could add between the `<main class="content">` and `<div class="list>`:

```
<h1 class="article-title">Home</h1>
```

If you want to source the title from the `.Rmd` file, you would do:

```
<h1 class="article-title">{{ .Title }}</h1>
```

Now after rebuilding the site the title will appear on the homepage.